# SAP GUI Connection not working after update to .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, wsh, sap-gui

I developed a .NET 4.6 Framework project (X64) with access to the running sap-instance.
to connect to sap i used the exactly same way as the SAP-Script:

Script-Version:

```
Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
...
```

.Net Framework 4.6.2 / .Net6 Version:

```
Dim SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Dim application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine`
Dim SAPCONN = application.connections(0)
Dim SAPSESS = SAPCONN.children(0)
SAPSESS.findById("wnd[0]").ElementVisualizationMode = False
```

In .NET Framework 4.6, I got access to an SAP system and the connection was working.

Now I updated to .NET 6 and the first code line (`SapGuiAuto`) reports this error:

> Fehler beim Laden der Typbibliothek/DLL. (0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Second line then crashes because object has no type `GetScriptingEngine`.
It looks like some files are missing but if this would be the case it should not work in .NET 4.6 project.

On the same computer, same installations if I try the same again in .NET 4.6.2, it is still working ... What am I doing wrong? Can it be that `GetObject` behaves not the same in different framework versions? What can I do to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!

NB: I already tried to add/and remove the COM libraries (`SAPFEwse`) from the project but this seems to make absolutely no difference if this is included or not...

I tried also to install the outdated nuget library "SAP.GUI.Scripting.Net".
which in fact is just ROT WRAPPER and the `SAPFEWSE` Library. Also no success with this Library.

Comment: Could [this one](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/07/28/tip-how-to-create-a-.net-core-com-library-to-use-it-with-abap-via-sap-gui-for-windows-ole/) help?

Comment: What is the target you compile for? If you are using COM objects, it should be set to a "windows" target, COM objects don't work on other platforms. Can you double check that that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.8 and .NET 6 are not compatible, there have been a lot of breaking changes. Basically .NET 5 / 6 / 7 are what has been called .NET Core in the past. The assemblies are not binary compatible. So basically you can't use a .NET 4.8 Assembly (SAP) in .NET 6. Check whether SAP offers a SDK for .NET Core / .NET 5 and above.